# colorbox issue loading links into the same colorbox

Tags: colorbox

im using colorbox to load a comparative table and then in the html opened into the colorbox have links, when i click on those links is opening a new tab/page. Im not being able to make it load into the same colorbox. This is the code to open the colorbox:

$(".modal1").colorbox({initialWidth:70, initialHeight:70, innerWidth:"1000", innerHeight:"780", transition:"elastic", opacity:"0.9"});

And then the httml loaded into it have href="" tags with the page i need to load in the same colorbox.

Thanx in advance!

Comment: did you set the link's `target` attribute? try `target="_self"`

Comment: Yes, that is not making the difference. Thanx!